# Proving that $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ $(n\in \Bbb N)$ is divisible by 10 when $n$ is not divisible by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I was solving some math problems to prepare for math contests and came across this one:

Prove that $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ $(n\in N)$ is divisible by 10 if and only if $n$ is not divisible by 4.

So, from what I understand, we have to prove that:

$1+16^n+81^n+256^n$ $(n\in \Bbb N)$ is never divisible by 10;

$1+2 \cdot 16^n+3 \cdot 81^n+4 \cdot 256^n$ $(n\in \Bbb N)$ is always divisible by 10;

$1+4 \cdot 16^n+9 \cdot 81^n+16 \cdot 256^n$ $(n\in \Bbb N)$ is always divisible by 10;

$1+8 \cdot 16^n+27 \cdot 81^n+64 \cdot 256^n$ $(n\in \Bbb N)$ is always divisible by 10.

The problem is, these equations seem even more complex than the starting one. How would you prove these? Am I on the right track or is there an easier and more elegant way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If $a \equiv b \pmod{10}$, then $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{10}$ for all $n$. That way you can simplify $16^n,\, 81^n\, 256^n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand how this will help me simplify that...

Comment: @DDomjosa: For instance, you can replace $256^n$ with $6^n$. And it is easy to see that $6^n\equiv 6 \bmod 10$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ is divisible by $10$ if and only if it's divisible by $2$ and $5$.

Clearly $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ is even for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, so let's work with mod $5$.

If $n=4k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z^+$, then:

$$1^k+16^k+81^k+256^k\equiv 1^k+1^k+1^k+1^k\equiv 4\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

If $n$ is odd, then:

$$1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n\equiv 1^n+2^n+(-2)^n+(-1)^n\pmod{5}$$

$$\equiv 1^n+2^n-2^n-1^n\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

If $n=4k+2$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$, then:

$$1^n+4\cdot 16^k+9\cdot 81^k+16\cdot 256^k\pmod{5}$$

$$\equiv 1+(-1)\cdot 1^k+(-1)\cdot 1^k+1\cdot 1^k\equiv 1-1-1+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

Answer (score 4):

The sum $S_n=1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ is clearly always even, so it suffices to show that it is divisible by $5$ if and only if $n$ is not divisible by $4$.

Working mod $5$, we have

$$S_n\equiv1^n+2^n+(-2)^n+(-1)^n=(1+2^n)(1+(-1)^n)$$

so we see that $S_n\equiv0$ mod $5$ if $n$ is odd, since $1+(-1)^n=1-1=0$ when $n$ is odd.  On the other hand, if $n=2m$ is even, then

$$S_n\equiv2(1+2^{2m})=2(1+4^m)\equiv2(1+(-1)^m)$$

so we see that $S_{2m}\equiv0$ mod $5$ if $m$ is odd, and $S_{2m}\equiv4\not\equiv0$ mod $5$ if $m$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

To be slightly more concise:

**Lemma**

For any  prime $p$, $x+x^2+\dots+x^{p-1}  \equiv x(1+x+\dots+x^{p-2}) \equiv x(\frac{x^{p-1}-1}{x-1}) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ iff $x \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Note the following:

$$1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n}\equiv 1+0+1+0 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$

$$1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+4^{n} \equiv 2^{n}+2^{2n}+2^{3n}+2^{4n} \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

From the fact that $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) of $5$, and from the **Lemma** since $n \not \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ .

Thus, we get that $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ is divisble by $10$ if $n \not \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Note that a generalization is possible: $1^{n}+2^{n}+\dots+(p-1)^{n} \equiv 0 \pmod {2p} \Leftrightarrow n \not \equiv 0 \pmod {p-1}$

Comment: @user236182 Probably should mention that, thanks!

Comment: @user236182 Fixed.

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion that $1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n \equiv 2^n + 2^{2n} + 2^{3n} + 2^{4n} \pmod 5$?

Comment: @DDomjosa $2^{2n}\equiv 4^n$, $2^{3n}\equiv 3^n$, $2^{4n}\equiv 1^n$ mod $5$. The reason powers of $2$ work here is because $2$ is a primitive root mod $5$. Also $3$ is a primitive root mod $5$, so also $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n\equiv 3^n+3^{2n}+3^{3n}+3^{4n}\pmod{5}$. However, powers of $1$ and $4$ won't work here, because they are not primitive roots mod $5$.

Comment: @user236182 I'll have to look into primitive roots a bit more thoroughly, still can't understand the concept fully. I'll come back later to your explanation, thanks!